# Solve for $x=x_1 + x_2 $ $\tanh(x_1)+ \tanh(x_2)- \tanh(x_1) \tanh(x_2)A=B$

Tags: calculus

I want to solve this for $x$ 
$$\tanh(x_1)+ \tanh(x_2)- \tanh(x_1) \tanh(x_2)A=B$$

Where $x=x_1 + x_2 $

Is it possible to make  the equation in the variable $x$ only ?

I have tried to do this : $$2(\tanh(x_1) +\tanh(x_2)) -2(1+ tanh(x_1) \tanh(x_2))A=2(B-A)$$

Which implies that :$$1-\frac{2}{\tanh(x)}A=\frac{(B-A)}{\tanh(x_1)+ \tanh(x_2)}$$

Thank you ...

Comment: what is exactly given here?

Comment: A and B are constants .

Answer (score 2):

No. For example, take $A=2$ and $B=1$; then the graph of the solutions to $\tanh(x_1)+ \tanh(x_2)- \tanh(x_1) \tanh(x_2)2=1$ looks like this:

[image]

This picture shows, at the very least, that any value of $x=x_1+x_2$ between $-2$ and $2$ (and more) is possible.

Comment: How did you graph this ? I mean we have $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the equation

Comment: The horizontal axis is the $x_1$-axis, the vertical axis is the $x_2$-axis. (Or vice versa, since the equation is symmetric in the two veriables.)